# `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types

Tags: rust, traits

```
trait Responder{
}

struct App;

impl App {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {}
    }
    fn service<T, B>(&self, routes: T) -> Self where T: Fn()-> impl Responder {
        Self {}
    }
}

struct Routes {
    data:String,
}

impl Responder for Routes{
}

fn routes() -> impl Responder {
    Routes {
        data: "Hello".to_string()
    }
}

fn main() {
    // let new_routes = routes;
    App::new().service(routes);
}
```

How do I pass a function a parameter that return `impl Trait` or in my case `impl Responder`.

The error that it gives is: `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't - the docs (and the error) are explicit that the `impl trait` syntax can only be used when returning a **value** from a function to help the compiler deduce things (about a value). In your case you are trying to say something about a generic **type**, which is not the same and thus this syntax cannot be used.

Instead, you have to specify a type, in your case a generic one with a constraint:

```
fn service<T, B>(&self, routes: T) -> Self where T: Fn()->B, B: Responder
```

assuming you did not need `B` for something else. Note `routes` returns a value with a specific type, not an `impl trait`, and this type is what you are trying to write out.

Comment: Check [here for the progress](https://rust-lang.github.io/impl-trait-initiative/) of enabling `impl Trait` in more places,